# Type error in application

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get this piece of haskell code to work, however I keep getting this error message:

```
> ERROR file:.\4.hs:9 - Type error in application
> Expression     : fact n div (fact m * fact (n - m))
> Term           : fact
> Type           : Int -> Int
> Does not match : a -> b -> c -> d
```

Here's the code:

```
fact :: Int -> Int
fact q 
 | q == 1 = 1
 | otherwise = q * fact(q-1)

comb :: Int -> Int -> Int
comb n m
 | n < m = error "undefined as n < m"
 | otherwise = ((fact n) div ((fact m) * (fact (n - m))))
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You can write `fact` shorter, e.g. `fact n = product [1..n]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `div` in the last line.

When you want to make a function infix, you have to write it between `. So, simply change the last line to:

```
| otherwise = ((fact n) `div` ((fact m) * (fact (n - m))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `div` as infix, but it is not an operator so you have to write it like this:

```
comb :: Int -> Int -> Int
comb n m
 | n < m = error "undefined as n < m"
 | otherwise = fact n `div` (fact m * fact (n - m))
```

or like this:

```
comb :: Int -> Int -> Int
comb n m
 | n < m = error "undefined as n < m"
 | otherwise = div (fact n) (fact m * fact (n - m))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
 | otherwise = ((fact n) div ((fact m) * (fact (n - m))))
```

but it should be

```
 | otherwise = ((fact n) `div` ((fact m) * (fact (n - m))))
```

(at least)

Basically, you are using an infix operator, you'll have to mark it using back-quotes.

However, in this case, to reduce the number of parantheses, I'll rewrite it as

```
 | otherwise = div (fact n) $ (fact m) * (fact (n - m))
```

Edit: `s/inline/infix`